# How to use fork to create a new process which will print its copy of arg?

Tags: argv

I have to Test argv by modifying this code and I have no idea what the question is asking me... I am just learning and very new to this whole thing.

use fork to create a new process which will print its copy of argv. The
parent process should also print its own copy of argv. Run the program and direct the
output to a temp file. Open the temp file and check if both child and parent processes
print the same set of arguments. Make sure the parent waits for its child before it
terminates.

````
   int printList(char **someList)
{
    int index=0;
    while(someList[index]!=NULL)
{
        printf("%s\n "someList[index]);
        index++;
    }
    return index;
}
int main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
>{...
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, forking a process spawns a new "child process" which is an exact copy of the memory and state of execution of the parent (except the return value of the fork() call itself will be different). So your question is asking you to do something like

```
int main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
int pid = fork();
int output_fd = file.open("temp.txt")
if(pid == 0) {//This is the child process
     fprintf(output_fd, "I am the child, my args are %s", argv);
     exit(0);
}

//This is the parent process, wait for child to terminate then print argv
wait(pid);
fprintf(output_fd, "I am the parent, my args are %s", argv);
}
```

In the output file, you should see the both the parent and child process printed their args and that they have the same argv, because memory is copied from parent to child process when you make a fork() call.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. I had to take my time and learn about file descriptors to understand your code. Then I tried running the code but I'm getting an error message telling me "file" is undeclared. (file.open).  I'm probably missing something very obvious, but I tried almost everything I could to fix it and no success. Any advice is appreciated.